# Fecha mal añadida en tabla SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos

Añado 2 datos a mi base mediante DBHelper que son el ID de usuario y la fecha, lo cual esto cada vez que hago una conexión a la app me lo guarda en la base.
Al visualizar los datos el ID lo marca bien pero la fecha aparece un 1 y no sé el motivo si le paso un String cualquiera hace lo mismo un 1 en su lugar.

Aqué es donde le mando al método que ingrese el ID más la fecha:

```
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new 
                    SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    getDate = new Date();
                    String date = dateFormat.format(getDate);
                    mydb.addMoves(String.valueOf(iConexion), date);
```

Y aquí es donde añado los movimientos de conexión y visualización:

```
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public boolean addMoves(String name, String date){
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error en la base", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.beginTransaction();
    boolean resultado = true;

    try{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DATE, date);
        values.put(USER, name);

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_MOVES, null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error Movimiento: " + e.getMessage());
        resultado = false;
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    return resultado;
}

    public ArrayList<String>getAllMoves() {
    ArrayList<String> listMoves = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        db = getReadableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error en la base", e.getMessage());
    }

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM moves", null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(!res.isAfterLast()){
        listMoves.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(USER))+" -> "+res.getColumnIndex(DATE));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return listMoves;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale ya descubría el porqué:

```
listMoves.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(USER))+" -> "+res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DATE)));
```

Hay que declarar ambos valores por separado como String. Y la fecha se puede añadir de esta forma queda más claro y es menos código a picar:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
date = formatoFecha.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```